# Unity - Call animation from foreach loop

Tags: c#, animation, unity-game-engine, foreach

I'm making a game that adds a random number or random events to the scene when a specific function is called. I'm trying to animate a text box that tells what each effect is one after the other. I have each effect add a string of text to a List and use a foreach loop to change the text in the text box, then set an animation trigger to animate the box moving across the screen. I cannot get the loop to wait until the animation has completed resulting in only the last effects texts being animated.

```
public class UIAnimation : MonoBehaviour {

    public Animator animator;
    public Text NBtext;
    public GameObject NBEffect;

    public void NiceBowlingEffects(List<string> Effects)
    {
        foreach (var Effect in Effects)
        {
            NBtext.text = Effect;
            print(Effect);
            StartCoroutine(Animate());
        }
    }

    private IEnumerator Animate()
    {
        animator.SetTrigger("SlideText");
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(.75f); //animation is .7 seconds
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because a coroutine *acts* like a seperate thread. So you are essentially looping through your forloop at a normal speed, starting all your coroutines at virtually the same time, and therefore setting all of your animation triggers at virtually the same time. What you would need to do is place the delay in the loop itself.

```
public void NiceBowlingEffects(List<string> Effects)
{
    StartCoroutine(Animate(Effects));
}

private IEnumerator Animate(Effects)
{
    foreach (var Effect in Effects)
    {
        NBtext.text = Effect;
        print(Effect);
        animator.SetTrigger("SlideText");
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(.75f); //animation is .7 seconds
    }
}
```

or you could make the NiceBowlingEffects the coroutine itself and simplify a bit.

Comment: Thank you so much, I was at my wits end and it was such a simple solution. You saved my day.